# pthread_join and pthread weird behaviour

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I have 2 processes each creating multiple threads(2 in this example) via below code. When I put pthread_join right below create it works but it always calls threads in order. I want to do the joins in a different loop as below. Problem is when I do that for some reason it creates doubles of same thread instead of 2 different threads.

So when thread runs it prints something like
"Thread 2.2 started
Thread 2.2 started
Thread 1.2 started
Thread 1.2 started"
Where first number is process no and second one is thread no.They should be"1.2 1.1 2.1 2.2". Can someone help please?

```
for(int i = 0; i<num_of_t;i++){
        struct threadst args;
        args.globalcp = globalcp;
        args.lock = lock;
        args.num1 = num1+i*((num2-num1+1)/num_of_t);
        args.num2 = args.num1+((num2-num1+1)/num_of_t)-1;
        args.threadid =i;
        args.pid = myOrder;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, findPrimes, (void *)&args);
        pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
    }

    //for(int i = 0; i<num_of_t;i++){
        //pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
    //}
```

Comment: You're passing the address of the same `struct threadst args` to all new threads and without any synchronization.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: num1 and num2 are undefined.

Comment: Alright I looked into it and I think G.M is right I corrected that istake that and now different threads are getting created. But each gets called twice. I am sure I made another mistake somewhere. Anyway Thanks

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, your problem requires that you extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are passing the same object at each thread creation (`&args`), it is thus shared among all threads. So give each it's own as you needed.

Second, don't call `pthread_join` just after thread creation or you will reintroduce sequentiality (join is a blocking operation waiting for the end of the thread). Usually you need to launch your threads, and at some subsequent point later in time call join on threads you need to wait for.

```
// create an array of args to be passed each for a given thread
struct threadst *args = malloc(sizeof(struct threadst)*num_of_t;
// need a test for malloc...

for(int i = 0; i<num_of_t;i++){
    struct threadst *arg = args+i;
    arg->globalcp = globalcp;
    arg->lock     = lock;
    arg->num1     = num1+i*((num2-num1+1)/num_of_t);
    arg->num2     = arg->num1+((num2-num1+1)/num_of_t)-1;
    arg->threadid = i;
    arg->pid      = myOrder;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, findPrimes, (void *)arg);
}

// do something else in the meantime

for (int i = 0; i<num_of_t;i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
}
```